# Android Studio "Error - Could not save project: null"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having an issue with android studio where I keep getting this dialog error every time I try to save a class or navigate through/away from the project:

"Error - Could not save project: null"

I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix it.  My android studio version is current at 1.1.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I followed the instructions at the bottom of the post here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62627

Which seemed to work for a while but the issue came back a while later.

UPDATE:

Tried re-installing Android Studio which worked for a while, now its back.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, i have tried to clean the project and reset android studio but it always returns after a while. Please let me know if you find a fix.

Comment: As of today I still have no idea whats causing it BUT I was VPN'd and getting it all the time, I disconnected my VPN and don't have the issue anymore...something to do with studio trying to communicate with your repo and having an issue with VPN?

Comment: I did not have an active VPN or proxy of some kind, but the answer for me was to disable the "Google cloud Tools for Android Studio"  plugin. I don't know when this was added but it was causing the issue for me.